# Puedo ejecutar consulta de acorde a valor recibido por GET?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7, condiciones

Tengo 3 tablas de registros en mysql que comparten el mismo campo en común llamado "PIN" y necesito que en PHP se pueda ejecutar una consulta o la otra dependiendo del el PIN recibido por método GET.

La razón de esto es por que:

-Mando el valor de **TABLA A** por método GET con ayuda de un botón. 
-Lo recibe el programa y decide si el valor "pin" se encuentra en **TABLA B** ejecutar consulta 1 y si el valor "pin" recibido se encuentra en **TABLA C** ejecutar consulta 2.

Estaba pensando usar una condicional pero no se como implementarla y también pensé en SWITCH CASE, agradezco su ayuda. ACTUALMENTE ESTE CÓDIGO FUNCIONA CON UNA SOLA CONSULTA que incluye dos tablas.

```
<?php
session_start();
pin_variable = $_GET['pin'];

$conectar = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "myDB"); 
$conectar -> set_charset("utf8"); 

//Consulta 1 para procesar operaciones
$cuenta = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM tablaB T INNER JOIN 
tablaA E ON T.pin = E.pin WHERE T.pin ='{$_GET['pin']}' ORDER BY 
T.pin ASC");
$total = mysqli_num_rows($cuenta); 

//Aquí va el código de operaciones
?>
```

En dado caso de que `pin_variable = $_GET['pin'];` se encuentre en tablaC ejecutar:

```
 //Consulta 2 para procesar operaciones 
 $cuentaDos = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM tablaC T INNER JOIN 
 tablaA E ON T.pin = E.pin WHERE T.pin ='{$_GET['pin']}' ORDER BY 
 T.pin ASC");
 $totalDos = mysqli_num_rows($cuentaDos);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo que haces `JOIN` en base a la columna `pin`, considero que los índices están configurados correctamente en base a esa columna.

Entonces, quizá sea más simple y menos costoso que hagas una sola consulta basada en `LEFT JOIN`. Así podrás determinar por los resultados en qué tablas coincide el `pin`.

La consulta sería esta:

```
$pin=$_GET['pin'];
$sql="
        SELECT 
            a.pin AS pinA, 
            b.pin AS pinB, 
            c.pin AS pinC 
        FROM tablaA AS a
            LEFT JOIN tablaB AS b ON a.pin=b.pin
            LEFT JOIN tablaC AS c ON a.pin=c.pin
        WHERE 
            a.pin=$pin 
            OR b.pin=$pin 
            OR c.pin=$pin
    ";
```

En esta consulta vas a tener un dataset parecido a este:

Cuando el pin esté en `tablaA` y `tablaB`:

```
pinA    |    pinB    |   pinC
---------------------------------
AAA     |    AAA     |   NULL
```

Cuando el pin esté en `tablaA` y `tablaC`:

```
pinA    |    pinB    |   pinC
---------------------------------
AAA     |    NULL     |  AAA
```

Dicho de otro modo, donde esté el valor `NULL` no estará el pin.